# What answer to accept when the helping answer is actually not an answer to the question asked

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If I ask a question that states that I want some specific type of an answer, 
and still one of the answers suggest something that "overrides" my question but still helps me.

Like if the question is "What is the best way to use a pen to write something" and you get an answer saying "you really should use a pencil" (actual case is more complex of course).

Should I accept the "best correct answer" or the "most helpful answer"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All accepting an answer means is

> This answer helped me the most.

So even if it didn't answer your *question*, but helped you solve your *problem* you should probably accept it.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to consider voting up those answers that either actually answer your question or you found helpful. Leaving a comment explaining that the accepted answer actually solved your problem but that some _other_ answer actually answers the more general problem (for example) wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: @cdeszaq - feel free to edit that information into the answer.

Comment: I would rather leave it as a comment, since I see it as related to the question, but not directly part of the answer. It's essentially "tangential" behavior and not _nearly_ as crucial as the core idea of picking what helped the most.

Comment: thanks, I will follow this advice.